# bitcoind daemon and createrawtransaction params

Tags: php, bitcoin, bitcoind

I've been testing/learning  the rpc interface for Bitcoind daemon, and using the php library successfully up until now.
 I am trying to create a new raw transaction, i got a  lot of example over internet but i don't know function's  params where should be comes from.

example :

```
$bitcoin = new Bitcoin('myuser','mypwd','127.0.0.1','8332');

 $bitcoin->createrawtransaction(
     array(
        array(
            "txid"=>"aed23bb3ec7e93d69450d7e5ea49d52fcfbef9d380108f2be8fe14ef705fcea5", /where this string comes from or how i have to generate it??
            "vout"=>2 //what is this vout, in this case what means the number 2??
        ),
    ),
    array(
        "1GTDT3hYk4x4wzaa9k38pRsHy9SPJ7qPzT"=>0.006,//destination wallet address and required amount
    ));
```

1. where  "txid" comes from, or how is it genarated
2. where vout value have to be comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [this description](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/12472). It's excellent.

(Very) Short version:

- The input of every transaction is output of an older transaction.
- `txid` Is the **Transaction ID** of a transaction you received (containing at least the value, you want to spend). `vout` is the index of your address in the original `txid`.

You can look at some actual transactions here: https://blockchain.info/